# How to pass data from endpoint to getSession() in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to pass an object from endpoint to `getSession`, which I believe they are all run in server. I can get the value passed with cookie but not those passed with `request.locals.<variable>`:

`src/hooks.ts`:

```js
import cookie from 'cookie'

export async function handle({request, resolve}) {
  const cookies = cookie.parse(request.headers.cookie || '')

  request.locals.accessToken = cookies.accessToken
  request.locals.refreshToken = cookies.refreshToken

  const response = await resolve(request)

  const accessToken = `accessToken=${request.locals.accessToken || ''}; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;`
  const refreshToken = `refreshToken=${request.locals.refreshToken || ''}; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;`

  response.headers['set-cookie'] = [accessToken, refreshToken]
  
  return response
}

export async function getSession(request) {
    console.log('check request local', request.locals)
  return {
    accessToken: request.locals.accessToken,
    refreshToken: request.locals.refreshToken,
    user: request.locals.user
  }
}
```

My endpoint:

```js
export const post: RequestHandler<Locals, FormData> = async(req) => {
    const name = req.body.get("name")
    const password = req.body.get("password")

    if (!name || !password) {
        return {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                message: "Missing username or password"
            }
        }
    }
    const { access_token, refresh_token } = await getAccessToken(name, password)

  req.locals.accessToken = access_token
  req.locals.refreshToken = refresh_token

    const user = await getUser(access_token)

    req.locals.user = user
  
  return {
    status: 302,
    headers: {
      location: '/lobby'
    }
  }
}
```

Should I run `getUser` in `handle`, if I want to pass data with `request.locals` to `getSession`?

**Edit**

I am actually able to get the value of `request.locals.user` after `const response = await resolve(request)`, but not before `resolve`. Why is that?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Having issues of my own. I don't know how to get the user data obtained in either `handle` or `getSession` to my page data.

Comment: Yes I do. The thing is data is being passed around exclusively with cookie. So if you need that, pass it with cookie.

Comment: security side note: the doc mention to not include access tokens in the getSession https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#getsession

Answer (score 9):

I pass data from my endpoint to `getSession` with a cookie set in the `handle` function as mentioned earlier by John:

```js
//  src/hooks.js

import cookie from 'cookie';

export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const cookies = cookie.parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
    event.locals.user = cookies.user || null;
    const response = await resolve(event);
    if (event.locals.user) {
        response.headers.set(
            'set-cookie',
            cookie.serialize('user', event.locals.user, {
                path: '/',
                httpOnly: true
            })
        );
    }
    return response;
};

export async function getSession(event) {
    return {
        user: event.locals.user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting user information in your hooks.ts's **handle()** (before `const response = await resolve(request)` is a good place for it. This is because if you're going to limit access to a page or endpoint based on who the user is (or a user role perhaps), you want that to happen before the page or endpoint are called.

Regarding your other question about why `request.locals.user` is not populated until after resolving the request, it seems like a bug to me. I can confirm the same behavior. You might want to submit it as an issue.